# Loading a solar panel when PCB is without power

Tags: solar-cell, space

I need to be able to load some solar cells even when the PCB is without power. The basic set up is as follows:

[image]

When the PCB is without power, the load on the solar cell should be R3 and the switch to the testing circuit needs to be closed. When the PCB is powered, I need to be able to use a MCU to turn off the switch to R3 so that the cells is able to be tested by a testing circuit. I was thinking of using MOSFETs - but I am unsure what their behaviour will be when the circuit is off. Is there any way to do this?

Solution: See answer

Comment: All switches need specs for each state. {V,I} On/off Define yours  BTW, Vpmt = Voc/Isc

Comment: An NC relay? A depletion mode MOSFET?

Comment: The text in your question seems to contradict the text in your drawing. You write "When the PCB is without power, the load on the solar cell should be R3", however in the drawing next to R3 you have "Switch here, by default open, closed by applying voltage from an MCU". Since the PCB being without power is assumedly the 'default' state, then surely you want the switch *closed* by default?

Comment: And for further clarification, when we refer to switches, "closed" means that the switch is able to conduct current because it "closes" the circuit, while "open" means that the switch blocks current from flowing because it's an "open circuit". A switch is not a gate in a fence its a valve in a pipe ...

Comment: _"I need to be able to load some solar cells even when the PCB is without power._ - Why?

Comment: @brhans apologies, I phrased that incorrectly in the diagram. To clarify, the switch to R3 should be by default closed. The Switch to the testing circuit should be by default open.

Comment: @BruceAbbott The solar cells are going on a rideshare cubesat. The PCB will not be provided with power at all times, however will be exposed to light intermittently. If the cells aren't loaded when exposed to light, they will degrade faster and affect test results. Also, there will be multiple of these subcircuits (one for each solar cell) which feed into a mux. The mux cannot be exposed to the solar cells unless it is powered on, and even when it is powered on, only one cell is being measured at a time and the rest should remain closed to the mux.

Comment: What's your power budget when the testing circuit is on?

Comment: Satellite, that rules out NC relay. I still don't see why you need to keep the solar cell loaded, but a depletion mode MOSFET would do the job for you.

Comment: Solar cells will not degrade faster if exposed to light and not loaded. There is no problem with not loading the solar cells

Comment: @SolarTec I have been told by the solar guy that in fact they will. They are perovskite based, and I think do in fact degrade at VOC

Comment: If open circuit voltage is an issue, how about just a Zener diode?

Comment: RRS100P03 is not a depletion mode MOSFET.

Comment: You are correct @BruceAbbott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this to be somewhat of a difficult problem to solve so here is my solution for anyone that is interested. Depletion mode NMOS used to keep closed switch for load at times cell is not needed. By applying a negative voltage this is opened. Enhancement NMOS used to keep usually open switch to rest of circuit. This is closed by applying a positive voltage. Negative power supply switch used so both can be operated simultaneously from an MCU

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given that your solar panel only puts out 10mA, a cheap little J111 JFET will do the trick. It has a Ron of 30 Ohm max, which would even allow you to omit the load resistor and instead rely on the JFET's on resistance. To turn it off, you will need a negative voltage (just as with depletion-mode MOSFETs), which you can generate with a micropower DC/DC converter like the LT3483. This of course means that the circuit will consume a few dozen microamperes when it's not shorting out the solar panel.

If you need to short out a beefier solar panel (i.e. multiple amperes), there are power JFETs like the UJ3N065080K3S.